# (Asp.net core) Why does the layout style not work when I display another view that is not the index

Tags: asp.net, routes, razor-pages

I am new in Asp.net, I have a little problem to  display the style of my razor view in Asp.net core, but this also happened to me with Asp.net MVC5, when I run the following route: **https://localhost:44373/ActeNaissances** the style applies of course to the Index but when I switch to **https://localhost:44373/ActeNaissances/Create** my view is displayed without style.
Do you have any idea on the source of my problem?

Comment: Make an external style sheet and call that in every page just in case if you don't have Layout pages. In this case ActeNaissances/Create might not have the stylesheet imported. To minimize your effort create a Layout page and write your external stylesheet link in it. Then, create razor pages that inherits Layout page. In this way your css would be reflected in all the pages that used Layout page.

Comment: I didn't understand, I already have a stylesheet that I called in my layout

Comment: Is your ActeNaissances/Create page inherits the Layout page? Or in other words, does Layout page serves ActeNaissances/Create page?

Comment: yes i have this on my create view  **Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";**

Comment: This might be some unusual thing. .Build your project > then go to the browser hard refresh your page by pressing Ctrl + Shift + R if you are on windows. (Not sure about Mac)

Comment: I found the problem, I just  add ** ~ / ** in the path of my style on the layout